# ג (gimel) mi yodeya (the pronunciation)?

Tags: minhag, hebrew, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

From a halachik perspective, what are the correct ways to pronounce the ג (gimel)? Are there variant traditions? Is there an academic/linguistic opinion on how it was most likely pronounced from the time of the giving of the Torah to the writing of the Talmud? How old are the 2 variant pronunciations of the gimel (with and without a *dagesh*)? What are the earliest references to this distinction? Is there any halachik significance to pronouncing it one way over the other? Is it just considered a *hiddur* (beautification of the commandment)?

Comment: Please include in this and any similar questions what you seek beyond the wikipedia page of the letter in question.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language) should  ever make it into beta..

Comment: Why did you stop at gimmel? ;)

Comment: g and gh are accepted by linguists. although j is how teimonim from sanaa pronounce it. j and gh, and although the j goes back to the babylonian captivity if not older, it is still not the way linguists say it is said to be pronounced. in arabic it is j and gh as well but the egpytians and adenites and some other group pronounce it as g and gh. http://vocaroo.com/i/s1yok1WxXHai here is my arabic pronunciation of the letters and here is the hebrew http://vocaroo.com/i/s1qIdB0rP4Yg

Comment: @intuit, have you used all of your upvotes for that yet?

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt: I have.

Comment: https://youtu.be/pSAu-wBvYHg?t=18s

Comment: Linguists agree that ג was [g] historically. Under Aramaic influence, ungeminated ג preceded by a vowel became [ɣ]. The latter sound was lost (or perhaps never gained) by some pronunciation traditions. Some Yemenite dialects adopted [d͡ʒ] for גּ from the local Arabic dialect.